# In Mysql,How can select new data from last select data

Tags: php, mysql

Use PHP.
then in mysql hava this table

```
Id     where    name    sex
1      CN       X.ming  boy
2      US       Tom     boy
3      US       jom     boy
4      US       Kim     girl
```

=====================

first i need get where `select * from table where=US`

then need get boy `select * from (last select) where sex=boy`

i find get code is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE where=US) AS a WHERE sex=boy；
```

but this not good and not fast.

case:

//
my English is no good,so i reply is slow... sorry!!

Comment: From your comments on the given answers I guess there's some confusion about what you're going to do, could give some more details?

Comment: I think you had better **give us an example of the output you want** from this query, as we all seem confused as to what you actually want

Comment: It seems to me, that all the answers below will get the same result as your query, but without having to process the table twice

Comment: I suggest you say *why* you want to do this so that we can understand the problem better. For example, you might say "I want to create a dropdown box for location, and when the user selects a location (e.g. 'US') then I want the user to select boy or girl from the next dropdown, so that when they select 'boy', the result shows only boys from US. This is two separate actions."

Comment: I'm fisrt time use stackoverflow .....and my English is no good ..but think everyone tell me and see queen peoples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change where from table to location

```
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "yourDB";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 


  $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE `location` = "US"');

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($row['sex']==boy) $data2[] = $row;
      $data1 = $row;
  }
```

$data1 contains list of US and $data2 contain list of boy in US

Comment: Sorry,It's not what I need ..  This case.. and  i need like choose class ,is Fist i need where ='US' ,then i choose sex = 'boy' ;every word is alone. ....like the shoping choose.

Comment: means step by step.. First where = "US" then from US list sex="boy"?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you cannot use reserve words in table column name (**recommended**). `where` is a reserve word, so change it to location or something else. And the query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE location = 'US' AND sex = 'boy';
```

Comment: Sorry,It's not what I need ..  This case.. and  i need like choose class ,is Fist i need where ='US' ,then i choose sex = 'boy' ;every word is alone. ....like the shoping choose.

Comment: You can use reserved keywords using backticks, although it's stupid

Comment: So what do you need? Please elaborate ?

Comment: @LarsBeck ya I know

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I assumed that ;)

Comment: If you want first a list of US peoples and than filter it with Boys, than you can do it with the above query in php.

Answer (score 2):

You are over complicating things, you can have more than one thing in the where clause

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `where`='US' AND sex='boy'；
```

Note you also need quotes around text values, and backticks around reserved words, `where` is obviously a reserved word. It would be a better idea to think of another column name for that column.

Also `sex` is normally recorded as `male` or `female` or even `M` or `F`  rather than boy and girl.

Comment: Sorry,It's not what I need ..  This case.. and  i need like choose class ,is Fist i need where ='US' ,then i choose sex = 'boy' ;every word is alone. ....like the shoping choose.

Comment: So you want a list of all people in the US and then another list of all the boys?

Comment: I do not think the OP understands what they want IMHO

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Well you had better put me into that group as well. :)

Comment: yes,first want where='US' as table1 ,and then i need sex='boy' from this table1

Comment: @abigeater the above statement does what you want in on line there's no need to write thousand lines for simple select

Comment: @abigeater Please edit your question, and add an example of the output you require

Comment: Maybe they need a union of records matching the 'US' and records matching `sex='boy'`?

Comment: @rene Yes that was one of the idea's I had as well, but until more details come out of the OP I am hanging fire on any original thinking ;)

Comment: @rene Last seen 15 mins ago, I am guessing she has given up on us :(

Comment: @abigeater OK, take you time

Comment: sorry!!!!!! my English is no good and i need you're say what in the google  translate

Comment: like shop web,now i buy shoes search and show a great many shoes;;i choose "Nike" then show Nike shoes or "Adidas" show Adidas shoes.. then i choose summer shoose,and boy shoose....

Comment: Maybe if you sowed us some of the PHP code, we would get a better idea about what you are trying to do

Comment: i come back home now ,///,,but,now i can't write code,and i write idea is no good and misdirect you're...."select * from table_name where from ".$from." and sex".$sex."";and $sex=“boy” or null;;;$from="=US" or null;;

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you chain the conditions?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `where` = 'US' and `sex` = 'boy';
```

Also, it's a bad idea to use [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) for column names (here: "where").

Comment: Sorry,It's not what I need ..  This case.. and  i need like choose class ,is Fist i need where ='US' ,then i choose sex = 'boy' ;every word is alone. ....like the shoping choose.

Answer (score 2):

Think smartly you can put as many columns  as you can in where clause.
by using operators like **'AND'** to check wehther both conditions are true, **'OR'** if any of defined condition is true.

for current situation just use.

```
select * from (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC) where sex = 'male'
```

Comment: Sorry,It's not what I need ..  This case.. and  i need like choose class ,is Fist i need where ='US' ,then i choose sex = 'boy' ;every word is alone. ....like the shoping choose.

Comment: select * from (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC) where sex = 'male'

Comment: is that what you need ?

Comment: yes,like this ,but this not good ,because i need choose very much option.

Comment: my english is no good..then,like shopping,choose 2-5 class(every choose is alone run select ).

Comment: like shoping ? is this another table ?

no problem use google translate.. and then write whole scenario... its seems easy...just you need little guidance..

Comment: I think `TOP` is a SQLServer syntax and not MySQL! :)

Comment: after his complete details

Comment: Very Thank,i use translate and my can..i think can you know this answer...but my show is no true